# Tymon JWT using database provider instead of eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen, json-web-token

I'm using https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth on my lumen application.

Here's my `composer.json`

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.3.*",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0@dev",
```

I've read a of tutorials on how to install. Some of which are:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/role-based-authentication-in-laravel-with-jwt
- https://laravelista.com/posts/json-web-token-authentication-for-lumen

I am able to make it work on my local and successfully return the token. But the problem is that instead of using eloquent on the provider that fetches data from `database.sqlite`, I want to use database as my driver.

With that, I have set

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table'  => 'user_table',
        // 'driver' => 'eloquent',
        // 'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

on my `config/auth.php`

Since it is now connection thru a database, it now uses the `DatabaseUserProvider.php`

I need to modify some codes though.

```
/**
 * Validate a user against the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, app('hash')->make($user->getAuthPassword()));
}
```

Notice that I added a `app('hash')->make()` when validating the password.

It then inject the retrieved user into the `GenericUser` object.

```
/**
 * Get the generic user.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser|null
 */
protected function getGenericUser($user)
{
    if (! is_null($user)) {
        return new GenericUser((array) $user);
    }
}
```

Since it is on the `GenericUser` object, it gives an error of:

```
Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser given
```

In order to fix this, I have to "hack" it by removing the `JWTSubject` injection on every method under the `tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php`

Is there a better way to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix it by making your authenticating user implement JWTSubject, which is the most right thing to do.

```
class GenericUser implements JWTSubject {
    [...]
}
```

But, since you're dealing with a Laravel native implementation, I'd suggest you to extend it and implement JWTSubject, instead of going everywhere in jwt-auth's code and remove the type-hints.